# How can I check the value of a dropdown menu in craft cms / twig?

Tags: twig, craftcms

I have a dropdown menu with 2 options

- Ordered
- Unordered

I want to check if the value is Unordered or Ordered

```
  {% set viewModel = {
     cards: content['cards'] ?? [],
     cardListType: content.cardListType ?? ''
   } %}


   {{ viewModel.cardListType|json_encode() }}
```

Returns this to me 
`{"0":{"label":"Unordered","value":"unordered","selected":true}}`

I want to check if the value of `viewModel.cardListType` is unordered and that it's selected.

I have tried

```
   {% if viewModel.cardListType.value is unordered %}
         <p>UNORDERED</p>
   {% endif %}
```

and

```
  {% if viewModel.cardListType.value:unordered %}
         <p>UNORDERED</p>
   {% endif %}
```

and several other variations of this.
I don't understand the documentation/ syntax for dropdowns in craft or twig.
Can someone please explain like I'm 5 how this works and how to check the value?
I am using Craft 3 if this changes the syntax

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the output of `cardListType` only contains one element?

Comment: @DarkBee It is a drop down with 2 options. Is the dropdown one element? Or is it the options? Ah DarkBee to my rescue again ;-)

Comment: Based on the output you've shown I would try [this](https://twigfiddle.com/2o15uh)